# convert string to mysql query using regex

Tags: mysql, replace, substring

I have mistakenly updated a column in a MySQL database and set every row to the same value like this:

```
ID  keyword                 Default_value   
1   header_HOME             EXCURSIONS
2   footer_APARTMENTS      EXCURSIONS
3   index_Excursions       EXCURSIONS
4   header_Sea_Excursions   EXCURSIONS
5   home_Desert_Safari      EXCURSIONS
6   header_Sight_Seeing     EXCURSIONS
7   apartment_Shore_excursions  EXCURSIONS
8   header_Plan_excursions  EXCURSIONS
9   header_Others           EXCURSIONS
10  header_Hotels           EXCURSIONS
```

to be like that

```
 ID  keyword                 Default_value   
    1   header_HOME             HOME
    2   footer_APARTMENTS      APARTMENTS
    3   index_Excursions       Excursions
    4   header_Sea_Excursions   Sea Excursions
    5   home_Desert_Safari      Desert Safari
    6   header_Sight_Seeing     Sight Seeing
    7   apartment_Shore_excursions  Shore_excursions
    8   header_Plan_excursions  Plan_excursions
    9   header_Others           Others
    10  header_Hotels           Hotels
```

Now I need to update the `Default_value` column to match this pattern:

1. Take the words in the `keyword` column.
2. Strip off the `header_` prefix.
3. Replace the underscores `_` with spaces .
4. Append `Excursions` on the end.

The result will be the equivalent of running a command like this for each row:

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET `Default_value` = 'Desert_Safari' WHERE `id` = 5
```

Comment: Common, there is nothing "critical" about it. Just String-Conversion. Well, somebody will do the work for you I assume.

Comment: What language would you be executing the regular expression in?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you want:

```
update table t
    set default_value = concat(replace(substring(keyword, 8), '_', ' '), ' Excursions')
```

I think this is easier with basic string functions than using regular expressions.

Comment: +1 I started writing and answer like this then realised I'd miss understood the OPs specs.This answer is correct IMO so I won't bother with a competing answer.

Comment: You need to concat "Excursions" to the end.

Comment: the keywords not only home_ it's variable i update my question

Comment: @shmosel . . . I do now.  The question changed after I answered it.

Comment: @tito11 . . . Changing your question after its been answered can invalidate answers.  That is considered impolite.